# Using Flurl to send a list of files to an asp.net core's IFormFileCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, flurl

I have an endpoint defined like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post( ... [FromForm] IFormFileCollection images) { }
```

Posting using PostMultipartAsync works well for individual streams, but how would I use this for a list of streams?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the upload part of the stream list? There is an [example](https://flurl.dev/) from

this question, which basically shows all the possibilities:

```
var resp = await "http://api.com"
    .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
        .AddString("name", "hello!")                // individual string
        .AddStringParts(new {a = 1, b = 2})         // multiple strings
        .AddFile("file1", path1)                    // local file path
        .AddFile("file2", stream, "foo.txt")        // file stream
        .AddJson("json", new { foo = "x" })         // json
        .AddUrlEncoded("urlEnc", new { bar = "y" }) // URL-encoded                      
        .Add(content));                             // any HttpContent
```

Official document: https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-url/